# What should be considered 'duplicate'

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I have seen questions marked as duplicate, which could be considered so only if/when the answer is known. A question I noticed this about is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45649501/cant-get-custom-header-with-http). Should these be considered duplicate? Obviously the OP asked it because he had no clue his issue was related to missing `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`. Similarly, Googlers finding the Q&A latter will also have no clue that is the issue. Isn't the question legit/useful then?

Comment: I can't wait until the sweet irony when this question will be marked as a dupe.

Comment: That the OP didn't know what the real issue or what to search for to find the answer doesn't matter wrt. the question being a dup. The issue is: do the answer(s) on the dup-target answer the question. If the question contains a different way to describe, or think about, the issue which results in the OP and others not being able to find the answer on the duplicate-target, without the duplicate there to point the way, then that's a *good* thing. We *want* duplicates like that. They do *exactly* what a duplicate is supposed to do: be a signpost helping people find the answer on the dup-target.

Comment: If I can highlight a few words in the title and the duplicate-target shows up at, or near, the top of the results when I select "Search Google for [selected words]", I usually feel that means the OP didn't do enough research. It will often get the question a down-vote from me. On the other hand, if it's an issue where what to search for is not clear and searching for terms in the question doesn't result in finding the dup-target, then it's a *good* duplicate which will help other people find the answer(s) on the dup-target. Such questions, when well written, can easily get an up-vote from me.

Comment: Don't mind me, I just have this compulsion to close all questions about duplicates as duplicates. :-)

Comment: @the4kman here we go! ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick to duplicates is that it is not a scarlet letter of shame to have thrown on your question. It tells you that there is someone else out there that has had a very similar problem. Often times a problem is only a conundrum to a programmer because they didn't know there was a tool already available or that there exists a very specific name for that type of problem.

Not knowing what the word is that they are even trying to search for doesn't absolve them of the responsibility for doing an exhaustive search first, but sometimes you need to put aside your experience bias. Using Oracle SQL as an example, I have seen numerous requests come up for putting a column of values into a comma separated list. If you've never heard of the `LISTAGG()` function before, that is a hard one to track down. A duplicate closure in that case can point a user to a very useful solution.

Personally, I only downvote a question like that unless it has severe content issues or looks like no attempt was made to even search for the answer. And again, sometimes I have to think about my experience bias before I do so. Finally, voting is very personal and is your own judgement call.

Finally, duplicate closure doesn't delete the post, it just prevents further answers on it. That tells you it is useful (pending other problems). If it were a complete waste of space, it would end up soft deleted. Instead, the duplicate remains on the site, serving as a "pointer" to the master question (because, like you mentioned, it may use different terms, and thus appear for different search queries) and thus *adding value*.

Comment: *"The trick to duplicates is that it is not a scarlet letter of shame to have thrown on your question."* Man, I would upvote that one hundred times if I could, just to get the message out there. Not only does it tell you that someone else had a very similar problem, but it *immediately* gets you to a solution that has been vetted by the community. From an asker's perspective, you can hardly dream of asking for anything better.